# Problem with Printing Content Of RichTextBox with Adorner Layers

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, richtextbox

I am trying to print the content of RichTextBox including the Adorner Layers inside.
I am using this code to print

```
        double w = Editor.ExtentWidth;  // Editor is the RichTextBox
        double h = Editor.ExtentHeight;

        LocalPrintServer ps = new LocalPrintServer();
        PrintQueue pq = ps.DefaultPrintQueue;
        XpsDocumentWriter xpsdw = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(pq);
        PrintTicket pt = pq.UserPrintTicket;
        if (xpsdw != null)
        {
            pt.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
            PageMediaSize pageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(w, h);
            pt.PageMediaSize = pageMediaSize;

            xpsdw.Write(Editor);
        }
```

The problem I'm facing is that this code only prints the content that is visible on the screen, not the whole content of the Editor.

**EDIT**
The *pictures are adorner layers*, If I print using the method above, it only prints the visible part on the screen not the whole document.

[image]

**Edit**

I'm trying to print each page separately but I cant force `Editor.InvalidateVisual();` after doing a `Editor.PageDown();` Is there a way I can do that in my method ?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this yesterday?

Comment: @LarsTech This covers a different problem.

Comment: Have you tried calling xpsdw.Write(Editor.Document) ?

Comment: @AresAvatar Yea it gives an error "cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument' to 'string' "

Comment: Is the issue the adorners, or that you aren't getting content that is out of view due to scrolling. If you need to print a "tall" document that must be scrolled when read on the screen, then you'd probably want to print the emedded flow document directly, rather than printing the RichTextBox.

Comment: @NathanAW I cant do this `xpsdw.Write(Editor.Document);`  It gives me `cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument' to 'string'`

Comment: Try this: `xpsdw.Write(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)Editor.Document).DocumentPaginator)`. That should call the `Write(DocumentPaginator documentPaginator)` overload of the XpsDocumentWriter.

Comment: @NathanAW It doesn't print the adorner layers, only the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any way that works 100% for this problem, so I'm trying to transform all my adorner layers to actual images. I'll update the question once I get a 100% working solution.

Answer (score 1):

When controls draw on the adorner layer, they search up the tree until they find an adorner layer. Often times this is a the window level. In some cases, you'll want an adorner layer closer to the control, or directly around the control. In this case, wrap the control with an `<AdornerDecorator><RichTextBox /></AdornerDecorator>`

In your case, you'd probably want to pass a parent element of adorner decorator, or the decorator itself to the print logic. This way the print logic would include the adorner layer as part of the visual. Maybe something like this:

```
<Grid Name="EditorWrapper">
   <AdornerDecorator>
      <RichTextBox />
   </AdornerDecorator>
</Grid>
```

Then, pass "EditorWrapper" to the print logic.

**EDIT**

If you just want to print the contents of the RichTextBox, then you might be best to use the built-in pagination capabilities of the FlowDocument. FlowDocument implements IDocumentPaginatorSource, which will return a paginator that can print the document. Pass that paginator to the XpsDocumentWriter and it should dump the content properly.

```
var doc = Editor.Document;
var src = doc as IDocumentPaginatorSource;
var pag = src.DocumentPaginator;
xpsdw.Write(pag);
```

Comment: I did this `<AdornerDecorator>
        <RichTextBox Name="Editor" />
        </AdornerDecorator>`
and I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931526/problem-with-printing-content-of-richtextbox-with-adorner-layers/6931772#6931772) code to print, but it didnt work

Comment: How do I pass `EditorWrapper` to the print logic?? :s

Comment: I also tried the code I posted above and passing `xpsdw.Write(EditorWrapper);` but it only printed the visible content on screen only.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what you're trying to print and what it actually prints?

Comment: you cant do this `var src = doc as IDocumentPaginatorSource;` It gives a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Answer (score 0):

I found this code [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prajakta/archive/2007/01/03/printing-contents-of-wpf-richtextbox.aspx):

```
// Serialize RichTextBox content into a stream in Xaml or XamlPackage format. (Note: XamlPackage format isn't supported in partial trust.)
TextRange sourceDocument = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
sourceDocument.Save(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);

// Clone the source document's content into a new FlowDocument.
FlowDocument flowDocumentCopy = new FlowDocument();
TextRange copyDocumentRange = new TextRange(flowDocumentCopy.ContentStart, flowDocumentCopy.ContentEnd);
copyDocumentRange.Load(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);

// Create a XpsDocumentWriter object, open a Windows common print dialog.
// This methods returns a ref parameter that represents information about the dimensions of the printer media.
PrintDocumentImageableArea ia = null;
XpsDocumentWriter docWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(ref ia);

if (docWriter != null && ia != null)
{
    DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowDocumentCopy).DocumentPaginator;

    // Change the PageSize and PagePadding for the document to match the CanvasSize for the printer device.
    paginator.PageSize = new Size(ia.MediaSizeWidth, ia.MediaSizeHeight);
    Thickness pagePadding = flowDocumentCopy.PagePadding;
    flowDocumentCopy.PagePadding = new Thickness(
            Math.Max(ia.OriginWidth, pagePadding.Left),
            Math.Max(ia.OriginHeight, pagePadding.Top),
            Math.Max(ia.MediaSizeWidth - (ia.OriginWidth + ia.ExtentWidth), pagePadding.Right),
            Math.Max(ia.MediaSizeHeight - (ia.OriginHeight + ia.ExtentHeight), pagePadding.Bottom));
    flowDocumentCopy.ColumnWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;

    // Send DocumentPaginator to the printer.
    docWriter.Write(paginator);
}
```

Comment: It doesnt print the images :(

Comment: I used `DataFormats.XamlPackage` but it didnt print the adorner layers

Answer (score 0):

Adorner layers are are drawing oriented. So one option left is to convert the entire RichTextBox into a drawing and print that as an Image in XPS.

Although this poses multiple issues...

1. It will print the external and internal contents that occupy or occupied by the richtextbox i.e. editor toolbar (if it is part of the control template of the rich text box), internal scroll bars etc.
2. If there are scrollbars then the content out of the scrollbars are not going to be printed as the image will be the exact "snapshot" of the textbox (with remaining text clipped by srollbars).

Will you be happy with that?

Comment: See this for creating a snapshot of a WPF UI control (in ur case the RichTextBox) ... http://mcleodsean.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/bitmap-snapshots-of-wpf-visuals/

Comment: Thats what I said in option 2... may be you can increase the height and width to 100% for an quick instance (without any user noticing the changed size) and do this snapshot call (which will have all contents) and change the size back to the original size !

Comment: I can do that, but the problem is what if I have more stuff in the richTextBox than the screen can show?